# Eclipse is forcing everything to be static

Tags: eclipse, function, static, call

For some reason after I had added and removed a static vairable from my code, eclipse started giving me errors on all functions that I call, saying that these functions must be static. However, if I let the program run with these errors, the program runs just as I intended it to do. My Code:

```
package main;

public class Main implements Runnable {

    public void start() {

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        System.out.println("Running...");

        Ball.test(); <--- Giving me an error

    }

    public void run() {

    }

    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
    }

}
```

and when I create a method in ball called test it gives me:

```
public static void test() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well yes - you're calling the method as if it were a static method:

```
Ball.test()
```

If you want to call an *instance* method, you need to call it on an instance, e.g.

```
Ball ball = new Ball();
ball.test();
```

It's important to understand the difference between static members and instance members. Have you read the [appropriate chapter of the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)? Do you have a good Java book which would help you? (Stack Overflow is great for specific questions, but not good for learning a language from scratch. Explaining language concepts well takes a lot of space and time.)